# Урок по изучению PHP

Tags: php

Вопрос 1:
При написании кода в:

```
function getAllGuestBookComments() {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();
    $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM 'guestbook'"); 
    closeDB();
    return resultSetToArray($result_set);
}
```

Браузер выдает вот такую ошибку

> Warning: mysqli_result::fetch_assoc() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in D:\OpenServer\domains\maisaite\lib\functions.php on line 35

Помогите решить.

Вопрос 2: 
При написании:

```
function getArticle($id) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();
    $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM articles  WHERE 'id' = 'id'"); 
    closeDB();
    return $result_set->fetch_assoc();
}
```

в браузерной строке `id` меняется, а `full_article.php` с базы данных текст и картинка остается `id1`.
Помогите решить. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В 1 примере вы не показали сам код ошибки, посмотрите что у вас в строке 35 в файле:

> D:\OpenServer\domains\maisaite\lib\functions.php

Не должно быть ничего в функции `fetch_assoc()` она должна вызываться без параметров, а у вас там есть какой то судя по ошибке, уберите его.

По поводу 2 вопроса:

Вы передаете в функцию переменную `$id` но в запросе не используете её, вот рабочий код:

```
function getArticle($id) {
    global $mysqli;
    connectDB();
    $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `articles`  WHERE `id` = '$id'"); 
    closeDB();
    return $result_set->fetch_assoc();
}
```

Только лучше бы ещё экранировать всё что передаете так в запросы.

Comment: Ну уж если человек на `mysqli` перешёл, не учите его переменные в запрос вставлять. Лучше же подготовленными запросами пользоваться

Comment: 35строка (connectDB(); в этом списке)    -   function addUser($email, $password) {
  global $mysqli;
  connectDB();
  $success = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('$email', '$password')");
  closeDB();
  return $success;

Comment: Извеняюсь: В этом строке     -   function addUser($email, $password) {
  global $mysqli;
  connectDB();
  $success = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES ('$email', '$password')");
  closeDB();
  return $success;
 }

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но вставил Ваш вариант без изменения?

Comment: Вот начальный код:  $mysqli = false;
 function connectDB() {
  global $mysqli;
  $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "maisaite");
  $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
 }
 
 function getALLArticles() {
  global $mysqli;
  connectDB();
  $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `articles`"); 
  closeDB();
  return resultSetToArray($result_set);
 }  Где   function getALLArticles() {
  global $mysqli;
  connectDB();
  $result_set = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `articles`"); 
  closeDB();
  return resultSetToArray($result_set);
 }  это intro_article.php   выводит

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM articles  WHERE id='{$id}'")
```

Comment: Добавьте пояснение к вашему ответу.